# DropNet Login Test

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropnet

So I'm just testing out the DropNet client for a new .net application I'm developing and I'm just trying to login by doing this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _client.GetTokenAsync((userLogin) =>
            {
            },
            (error) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error getting Token");
            });

        var uLogin = _client.GetToken();

        var url = _client.BuildAuthorizeUrl(uLogin);

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);

        _client.GetAccessTokenAsync((accessToken) =>
            {

            },
            (error) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error getting Access Token");
            });


    }
```

And then trying to display my Account information in a message box by doing the following:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _client.AccountInfoAsync((accountInfo) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(accountInfo.ToString());
            },
            (error) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error displaying data");
            }
            );
    }
```

The error message displays when button 2 is clicked.

I've also declared my `DropNetClient _Client = new DropNetClient("API KEY", "API SECRET");` at the top of the class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error being displayed by the MessageBox in button 2. `(error) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error displaying data");
            }
            );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating asynchronous calls as though they're synchronous.

Each async call needs to wait for the previous to return before continuing.

This is done by making use of the success Action of each Async call and in the case of Process.Start() using the Process.WaitForExit() call before continuing.

Finally, Process.Start() must explicitly use iexplore as not all browsers return a process (Chrome for example).

```
    public string UserToken { get; set; }
    public string UserSecret { get; set; }

    private DropNetClient _Client;
    public DropNetClient Client
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Client == null)
            {
                _Client = new DropNetClient(AppKey, AppSecret);

                if (IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    _Client.UserLogin = new UserLogin
                    {
                        Token = UserToken,
                        Secret = UserSecret
                    };
                }

                _Client.UseSandbox = true;
            }

            return _Client;
        }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get
        {
            return UserToken != null &&
                UserSecret != null;
        }
    }

    public void Authenticate(Action<string> success, Action<Exception> failure)
    {
        Client.GetTokenAsync(userLogin =>
        {
            var url = Client.BuildAuthorizeUrl(userLogin);
            if (success != null) success(url);
        }, error =>
        {
            if (failure != null) failure(error);
        });
    }

    public void Authenticated(Action success, Action<Exception> failure)
    {
        Client.GetAccessTokenAsync((accessToken) =>
        {
            UserToken = accessToken.Token;
            UserSecret = accessToken.Secret;
            if (success != null) success();
        },
        (error) =>
        {
            if (failure != null) failure(error);
        });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Authenticate(
               url => {
                   var proc = Process.Start("iexplore.exe", url);
                   proc.WaitForExit(); 
                    Authenticated(
                        () =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Authenticated");
                        },
                        exc => ShowException(exc));

               },
               ex => ShowException(ex));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Client.AccountInfoAsync((a) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.display_name);
        },
        ex => ShowException(ex));
    }

    private void ShowException(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error from the following snippet: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Authenticate(
               url =>
               {
                   var proc = Process.Start(url);
                   proc.WaitForExit();
                   Authenticated(
                       () =>
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("Authenticated");
                       },
                       exc => ShowException(exc));

               },
               ex => ShowException(ex));            
        }`

Comment: The error message is on line `proc.WaitForExit();` and it's Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which means proc isn't being instantiated by Process.Start(url), suggesting that url isn't being populated correctly by BuildAuthorizeUrl(). Presumably the browser isn't launching? Given that my test app works with the above code you might want to breakpoint and find what value url has in your case. I think I'll add my client instantiation code as well for a slightly more complete solution.

Comment: The browser is launching and when I step in I can actually see the url value but it's like the `proc.WaitForExit();` method isn't waiting at all. Thanks for your help @Michael

Comment: My test app is Wpf. What platform are you using?

Comment: Yes, but what type of project? Wpf, Winform, Windows Phone etc?

Comment: I've updated the code to include everything bar the AppKey and AppSecret string constants. I've just pasted the code above into a WinForms project and it worked first time. I can only suggest you check through your code again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76806/discussion-between-michael-phillips-and-rob-gleeson).